# What is the format specifier used for counters in perf?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, perf

There is a `perf stat` option "interval-print", given as `-I N` where `N` is a millisecond interval to use for printing a counter every `N` milliseconds (`N` >= 10), and its output goes like:

```
./perf stat -I 1000 -e event_name
time                       counts unit   event_name
1.001177595                110           xyz
```

Now, I need to know what is the format specifier used for the "counts unit" column, which is coming from [`tools/perf/util/stat-display.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.12/source/tools/perf/util/stat-display.c#L1265).

Comment: Two issues, 1- posting a link to source code is not a good idea.   Cut and paste the relevant parts of source code you want to talk about directly  into the editor  here.   2 - if you search for _"counts unit"_ in the source code linked, you will not find it.   Can you be more specific on what you are looking for?

Comment: And if you do post a link to a line number, link to it in a particular version of the file, not "latest", because the line number in "latest" is likely to point to some other part of the code in the future.

Comment: If you are referring to this instance for example:  `static bool is_mixed_hw_group(struct evsel *counter)`, `counter` is a pointer instance to a struct.  There is no format specifier for a `struct`, only some of it's members.  If you want to print out the address of the pointer, you can use `"%p"`

Comment: @ryyker, perf stat -I outputs "count units" like 110 , and need to know what format specifier is used for this count units ?

Comment: That depends on what `type` it is.  `100` could be one of many types, each having its own format specifer, eg `unsigned short int`, `short int`, `long`.   There is not enough information in `100` without other context to know what `type` it is

Comment: Please edit your post and include enough context/content that includes how this is used, and it may be possible to determine `type`, and from that the right format specifier can be determined.  You will be increasing your chances of getting a quick and accurate answer from including the relevant code directly into your post. :)

Comment: The column heading is formatted in lines 1040-50 `fprintf(output, "             counts %*s events\n", unit_width, "unit");` The *values* in that column are a bit harder to track down. It's not easy to follow: the next column heading "event_name" doesn't appear in clear either.

Comment: @WeatherVane that's because `event_name` is a made up name by OP (`-e event_name`). It'd probably just be another `%s`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli ah I get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: format specifier `%'18.0f`, variable of type `double`.

---

A simple inspection with [`ltrace`](https://manned.org/ltrace.1) + `gdb` uncovers the format specifier used for printing:

```
$ uname -r
4.19.0-20-amd64
$ sudo ltrace -e '*fprintf*' perf_4.19 stat -I 1000 -e branch-misses
#           timeperf_4.19->__fprintf_chk(0x7fcde97d1680, 1, 0x55a2b46652c0, 4             counts unit events
)                                                          = 32
     1.001800886 perf_4.19->__fprintf_chk(0x7fcde97d1680, 1, 0x55a2b46596ab, 0x55a2b4770d89         2,536,128 )                                             = 19
perf_4.19->__fprintf_chk(0x7fcde97d1680, 1, 0x55a2b46596be, 4     )                                                          = 5
perf_4.19->__fprintf_chk(0x7fcde97d1680, 1, 0x55a2b46582ba, 25branch-misses            )                                                         = 25
perf_4.19->__fprintf_chk(0x7fcde97d1680, 1, 0x55a2b46582ba, 35
...
```

```
$ sudo gdb --pid $(pidof perf_4.19)
(gdb) b __fprintf_chk
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7fd72c20de60: file fprintf_chk.c, line 26.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, ___fprintf_chk (fp=0x7fd72c2c1680 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>, flag=1, format=0x556d2f5cd6ab "%'18.0f%s") at fprintf_chk.c:26
26  fprintf_chk.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) x/s 0x556d2f5cd6ab
0x556d2f5cd6ab: "%'18.0f%s"
```

```
$ cd linux_source
$ git describe --tags
v4.19
$ rg -g 'tools/perf/**/*' -F "%'18.0f"
tools/perf/builtin-stat.c
1081:           fmt = floor(sc) != sc ? "%'18.2f%s" : "%'18.0f%s";
```

[Here it is in the source code for Linux v4.19](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/tools/perf/builtin-stat.c#L1081), and [here for the latest v5.18.12](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.12/source/tools/perf/util/stat-display.c#L363):

```c
static void abs_printout(struct perf_stat_config *config,
             struct aggr_cpu_id id, int nr, struct evsel *evsel, double avg)
{
    FILE *output = config->output;
    double sc =  evsel->scale;
    const char *fmt;

    if (config->csv_output) {
        fmt = floor(sc) != sc ?  "%.2f%s" : "%.0f%s";
    } else {
        if (config->big_num)
            fmt = floor(sc) != sc ? "%'18.2f%s" : "%'18.0f%s"; // <===
        else
            fmt = floor(sc) != sc ? "%18.2f%s" : "%18.0f%s";
    }

    aggr_printout(config, evsel, id, nr);

    fprintf(output, fmt, avg, config->csv_sep);

    // ...
}
```

The function used is `fprintf` and the format specifier is `%'18.2f` or `%'18.0f` depending on if there are decimals to print or not. [The printing happens here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.12/source/tools/perf/util/stat-display.c#L370) and the variable being printed is `double avg`.

Comment: tried the steps as you mentioned but getting this message while attaching the GDB. "ptrace: Operation not permitted"

Comment: @Milan if you take a look at my post, I use `sudo gdb ...`

Comment: Yes, tried exactly the same way. But still same issue, and tried echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope. May I know your gdb version ?

Comment: @Milan don't know what the problem could be exactly, if you use `sudo` you should have all the privileges needed. I have `ptrace_scope` set to `1` and it works fine. Also, only root can write there: use `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` (it's important to NOT use `sudo echo 0 > ...` instead, which is wrong).

Comment: one follow up question, tried to look for abs_printout using ltrace, something like: ltrace -e '*abs_printout*' ./perf stat -I 1000 some_event but there is nothing in the output? does it mean perf binary is missing symbol information ?

Comment: @Milan `ltrace` traces *library function calls*, not calls to functions in the binary itself. You will need a debugger for that, and the binary should have been compiled with symbols (yours probably was not, like any other `perf` tool shipped in standard distro packages). You can however download kernel sources and compile it yourself if you want (not exactly sure if that one would contain symbols or how to prevent them from being stripped if not, that'd be up to you to figure out). Then, using GDB you can run it and add breakpoints where you want to inspect.