# examine function argument using GDB

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

I am new to GDB, and need to examine content of function using gdb. The program need to be debugged is perf and  function name is ___fprintf_chk() , and tried some thing like:

```
 perf stat -I 1000 -e branch-misses

    time             counts unit events
    1.000222090               1746      branch-misses                                               
    2.000486444               1986      branch-misses                                               
    3.000712797               1783      branch-misses
```

```
   sudo ./gdb --pid $(pidof perf)
   GNU gdb (GDB) 10.2
   Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
   This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
   There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
   Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
   This GDB was configured as "aarch64-none-linux-gnu".
   Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
   For bug reporting instructions, please see:
   <https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
   Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
   <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

   For help, type "help".
   Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
   Attaching to process 38977
   Reading symbols from /usr/bin/perf...

   warning: Unable to determine the number of hardware watchpoints available.

   warning: Unable to determine the number of hardware breakpoints available.
   Reading symbols from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0...
   (No debugging symbols found in /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0)
   Error while reading shared library symbols for /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0:
   Cannot find user-level thread for LWP 38977: generic error
   Reading symbols from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1...
   (No debugging symbols found in /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1)
   Reading symbols from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6...
   (No debugging symbols found in /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6)
   Reading symbols from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2...
   (No debugging symbols found in /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2)
   Reading symbols from /lib/libopencsd_c_api.so.1...
   --Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--q
   Quit
  (gdb) b __fprintf_chk
  Breakpoint 1 at 0xaaaae55b2614
  (gdb) c
  Continuing.

  Breakpoint 1, 0x0000aaaae55b2614 in __fprintf_chk@plt ()
  (gdb) info args
  No symbol table info available.
```

Now, need to know when break point is put at __fprintf_chk, does it on __fprintf_chk that is part of perf binary or from other shared objects (.so files, as I see Reading symbols from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0...)

Also, info args gives nothing, does it mean perf need to be compiled with debugging info (how)?

Comment: `__fprintf_chk` is an alternative name for the standard C library function `fprintf`.  The odds of your genuinely having encountered a bug in `fprintf` are very, very low.  Please describe, in excruciating detail, the symptoms you actually observed, that made you think this function was malfunctioning.

Comment: I am just after reproducing what has been pointed here to get the _fprintf_chk argument values, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73039094/what-is-the-format-specifier-used-for-counters-in-perf/73040015?noredirect=1#comment129073069_73040015

Comment: What is the output of `info sym __fprintf_chk` ? This will tell you the name of the shared library.

Comment: What GNU/Linux distribution are you using? This will determine if and how you can install a version of the shared library that has debugging info.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, info sym __fprintf_chk suggest that it is from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6. is there a way to pick from specific binary, say from perf binary file ?

Comment: @Milan Sorry, can you clarify what it is you want to pick?